# How to derive the Vortex line segment parallel to a plane using the Biot-Savart law?

Tags: vortex

I am trying to understand what is shown in this book [(Applied hydro and aeromechanics), page 187](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=Ds-bd0zAwIYC)

The velocity induced at a given point on a parallel plane by a vortex segment of length $b$, and strength $\Gamma$ is shown to be,

$v_1 = \frac{\Gamma b \, sin \, \alpha}{4 \pi R^2}$

Can anyone please show the steps on arriving this formula by applying Biot-Savart law ?

Comment: Please don't [double post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/313394/biot-savart-vortex-line-segment-parallel-to-a-plane) messages.

Comment: Meta post explaining why not to double post is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/335608)

Comment: I have [answered this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/345410/161132) on physics.SE.